# Modifying the Keycloak admin UI Client menu

Tags: keycloak, identity-provider

I was trying to create a connection between client and multiple IDP. In order to manage the IDP mapping, I needed a section inside client.

Is it possible to add an extra tab in client section of keycloak admin UI, as in the following image? If possible can you please guide me, how to achieve that?

[image]